# exponential function returns zeros

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I'm trying to draw the values of exponential function flowed in the below paper link, however, they are always zero. I'm trying to draw the gray image shown in the paper. What's your suggestions for this? Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KyvO.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPend.png

```
Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image.Width, pictureBox1.Image.Height);
            Color color = new Color();
            double Cb,Cr,r,g,b,R,G,B; 
            double CbMean = 156.56;//150.3179;
            double CrMean = 117.43;//117.1057;
            double K1 = 160.13;
            double K2 = 12.143;
            double K3 = 12.143;
            double K4 = 299.46;

            for (int i = 0; i < pictureBox1.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < pictureBox1.Height; j++)
                {

                    color = bm.GetPixel(i, j);
                    R = Convert.ToDouble(color.R);
                    G = Convert.ToDouble(color.G);
                    B = Convert.ToDouble(color.B);
                    if (R != 0 && G != 0 && B != 0)
                    {
                        r = R / (R + G + B);
                        g = G / (R + G + B);
                        b = B / (R + G + B);
                        Cb = (-0.169 * r - 0.331 * g + 0.500 * b);
                        Cr = (0.500 * r - 0.418 * g - 0.082 * b);
                        Cb -= CbMean;
                        Cr -= CrMean;
                        double CbDist = (K1 * Cb) + (K3 * Cr);
                        double CrDist = (K2 * Cb) + (K4 * Cr);
                        double CbDist1 = (-0.5 * Cb) + (-0.5 * Cr);
                        double dist = CbDist + CrDist;
                        double dist1 = CrDist1;
                        double gmm = Math.Exp(dist * dist1); //<-------zero
                        int luma = (int)((gmm * 0.3) + (gmm * 0.59) + (gmm * 0.11));
                        bmp.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(luma, luma, luma));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Have you checked the values of `dist` or `dist1` are not zero before passing them to `Math.Exp()`.  I suspect `Convert.ToDouble(color.R)` isn't working.  May need something like `R = (double)bm.GetPixel(x, y).R / 255;`

Comment: @FelixCastor thanks, I checked the values of dist and dist1 and they're not a zeros. Also, I checked the values of RGB it's working.

Comment: Is one of `dist` or `dist1` negative? If so, then `(dist * dist`)` will be negative and so `gmm` may be very small.

Comment: @RogerRowland Yes, one of them are negative

Comment: Then that's why `int luma` is zero - `Math.Exp` of a negative number will always be < 1.0, so when you cast to `int` you get zero.

Comment: @RogerRowland Thanks for the advice, but (luma) must be int because of the SetPixel only accepts int values. What do you suggest?

Comment: Well from a brief look at the paper you linked to , it seems to me that youe `Math.Exp` should be calculating a probability that you then threshold to decide whether to set the pixel to white or black. If you want to show the probabilities, try rescaling like `int luma = (int)(255.0 * gmm)`. The current equation `(gmm * 0.3) + (gmm * 0.59) + (gmm * 0.11)` is just equal to `gmm` anyway!

Comment: @RogerRowland Thanks for the suggestions, I did what you said, however, I got the same results. I think there is something missing in the paper.